# How do I rip audio from a DVD?

Tags: sound, dvd, transcode, dvd-audio

I remember reading a long time ago how you can rip the audio (music) from a DVD and convert it to a usable/readable format.

I can't find that article any more. Can anybody help me?

Comment: I've successfully used [dvd::rip](http://www.exit1.org/dvdrip/) together with [these](http://www.gentoogeek.org/steves_world/linux_dvd_audio_rip-tips_html) tips.

Answer (score 9):

1. Inspect DVD with following command

   ```
   pg@pipoTower: ~$ tcprobe -i /dev/sr0
   ```

   look for line where chapters is like following:

   ```
   [dvd_reader.c] DVD title 1/1: 17 chapter(s), 1 angle(s), title set 1
   ```
2. Rip all titles to mp3 where for example {1..17} is the number of chapters of your dvd

   ```
   for i in {1..17};do 
     transcode -x null,dvd -y null,tcaud -i /dev/sr0 -T 1,$i,1 -a 0 -E 44100,16,2 --lame_preset medium -m ~/tmp/yourDestinationMp3File_chapter${i}.mp3;
   done
   ```

   For details of command:

   - -T title,chapter,angle (described by your tcprobe command in point 1.)
   - -a audioTrackNumber
   - -i inputDevice
   - --lampe_preset can be: medium, standard, extreme refer to man transcode for further details

Comment: What would the transcode command look like when the DVD title line is `DVD title 1/11: 3 chapter(s), 1 angle(s), title set 1`? Thank you.

Comment: @MountainX try to replace the 17 by your chapters number which in your case is 11, so it'll be      for i in {1..11};do 
 transcode -x null,dvd -y null,tcaud -i /dev/sr0 -T 1,$i,1 -a 0 -E 44100,16,2 --lame_preset medium -m ~/tmp/yourDestinationMp3File_chapter${i}.mp3;
      done

Comment: Great, works for me. I would only change: for i in {1..17} to for i in {01..17} to have names easier to sort.

Answer (score 6):

Here's what you're looking for: [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/).

It's a fairly useful tool for what you're trying to do. To install, add the ppa `ppa:stebbins/handbrake-releases` to your software sources ([here's how to do that](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them/5102#5102)) and install handbrake from the Software Center.

Comment: It don't seem to have x64 version. If I try to install x32 -- I'm suggested to remove tons of x64 libs.

Comment: Sorry, but see the [Handbrake FAQ](https://trac.handbrake.fr/wiki/SupportFAQ#just-audio): Handbrake can't extract _only_ audio.

Comment: @MartinSchröder yes, and no. If you get this, then you can export it using VLC or something.

Answer (score 2):

For a proper Ubuntu approach I'd suggest to have a look into ffmpeg (command line). Example:

```
ffmpeg -i infile.wmv -vn -acodec copy outfile.wma
```

Or, if you want an MP3 file:

```
ffmpeg -i infile.avi -vn -ar 44100 -ac 2 -ab 192 -f mp3 outfile.mp3
```

Also there is another PPA software called [Gnac](http://gnac.sourceforge.net/); it's a GNOME software that uses the Gstreamer media framework and has a GUI.

Launchpad PPA: https://launchpad.net/~gnac-team/+archive/ppa

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnac-team/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnac
```

Comment: Use K3B to rip audios from DVD. Search on ubuntu software center, there you will find many apps regarding ripping audio/video data from dvds.

Answer (score 2):

Building on this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24326/how-do-i-rip-audio-from-a-dvd/516190#516190) and this [post](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-rip-dvd-audio-to-mp3-or-ogg.html), I came with a similar solution for extracting *uncompressed* WAV files. Use `tcprobe -i /dev/sr0` or `lsdvd` to determine the DVD title with the chapters of interest, then (assuming 17 chapters in title 1):

```
for i in {1..17};do 
  transcode -i /dev/sr0 -x dvd -T 1,$i,1 -a 0 -y wav -m /tmp/track${i}.wav
done
```

In my case this results in WAV files containing `lpcm 16bit 48kHz 2Ch`, same as the tracks on the DVD. You can check the resulting files using `mediainfo`.

Answer (score 1):

Use VLC's "open media" menu option to open the DVD, set the title to the one you want (you may have to explore the DVD by actually starting to view it, to get the title number).

Then instead of telling VLC to play it, tell it to stream it to a file.

Works great - you may have to use audacity to trim the results, as VLC will go back to the menu after playing the title you selected... so you'll get the menu track on infinite repeat at the end of your file :)

Answer (score 1):

Since `transcode` is not available as a package anymore in recent Ubuntu releases, some older answers don't work anymore. Here's an alternative solution using `mplayer` and `ffmpeg`:

First, make sure to install mplayer and ffmpeg:

```
sudo apt install mplayer ffmpeg
```

Then, dump the DVD's content using mplayer:

```
mplayer dvd:// -dumpstream -dumpfile output.vob
```

Now, rip convert it to an audio file using ffmpeg (which will also omit the video content):

```
ffmpeg -i output.vob -vn -f mp3 output.mp3
```

If your DVD has multiple chapters and you want to keep this structure, start by checking the chapters using mplayer:

```
mplayer -identify dvd://
```

Then, dump each chapter (in this example, chapter 1 - 5):

```
for i in {1..5}; do 
   mplayer dvd:// -chapter $i-$i -dumpstream -dumpfile $i.vob; 
done
```

Now, convert all of them again

```
for i in *.vob; do 
   ffmpeg -i $i -vn -f mp3 ${i/vob/mp3}; 
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install abcde
abcde
```

Wait half an hour. Current directory contains one `.ogg` track per file.

Similar question: [What are some CD Ripping Programs you can use on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1881/what-are-some-cd-ripping-programs-you-can-use-on-ubuntu)

Comment: `abcde` doesn't seem to work with DVDs. Fails with `[WARNING] something went wrong while querying the CD... Maybe a DATA CD?`.

Comment: @landroni thanks for the report. What version, and what DVD did you use if you can tell? I think it worked for me when I tested it, but I don't have any DVDs at hand anymore.

Comment: It was version 2.5.5. The DVD is a common DVD with a concert on it, with 23 chapters. And it failed here to initialize at all.

Answer (score 0):

Although the problem has been resolved, I still want to share another great Linux DVD ripping freeware I love – [AcidRIP](https://sourceforge.net/projects/acidrip/). AcidRIP is small and efficient, and allows me to transcode my DVDs just one button click.