# How to rip an audio track in flac from a DVD video?

Tags: 12.10, dvd, cd-ripping, flac

More and more audio CD are sold together with a DVD video containing bonus tracks. I want to rip only the audio part of those videos using a losseless audio codec, ideally flac for me.

Is there an easy way to rip audio tracks from a DVD video in flac?

Note : my question is specifically about flac encoding, I don't think it should be marked as a duplicate of question [How do I rip audio from a DVD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24326/how-do-i-rip-audio-from-a-dvd).
Moreover the answers of the previous question are not really relevant in my case.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/24326/how-do-i-rip-audio-from-a-dvd

Comment: I've already read it. Handbrake can't skip the video part (only produces .mkv or .mp4), same for dvd::rip. Acidrip doesn't have a flac option.

I'm looking for a easy way to do it and I want to avoid using the command line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Audacity

1. Install Audacity: `sudo apt-get audacity`
2. Then, play your DVD with the player you want (VLC, Totem, ...), be sure that it uses Pulse Audio for output
3. In Audacity, record the sound from Pulse Audio in a stereo track
4. Edit if necessary (face in, fade out) and export it as flac.

There is other ways. For example, you can use jackd and Ardour, if you want to record separate tracks for every 5.1 channels '6 tracks) and mix them.

## VLC

1. Open your DVD with VLC
2. Select the chapter you want to rip
3. In options, choose the audio output -> file and select the kind of file you want (flac)
4. Click play
5. VLC will write the file

Comment: I understand you solution but it's not convenient at all. If a repeat the process twice, I'll never get exactly the same song since I need to edit the recording to remove what was before and after I've play the song...

Comment: in Audacity, there is an option to wait for sound in the inputs to record. So it will wait for you to press "play" in the player. the end of the song, you will have to cut it manually, it is true. An other way is to use jack and sync the player, ardour and jackd transport so every applications will start and stop together; ardour is used to record in this case, but it is not so easy to configure.

Comment: you are welcome. do you want me to put details about how to do that in multitrack (5.1) with ardour ?