# How to install Ruby Ripper, or another app that does MP3s through a GUI

Tags: music, ruby, mp3

I have tried to install ruby ripper various times (raring) using code pasted from the internet.  everytime i get to sudo apt-get install rubyripper, i get this back:

> E: Unable to locate package rubyripper

I would like to install something that will let me rip mp3s, and modify the rip setting.

Rhythm box seems to only rip a thing called ogg vorbis.  I would like to install something that will let me rip mp3s through a gui.

Answer (score 6):

***Simplest method.***

### UPDATED: 2016-Aug

Add the *Get-Debian* 'Apps' archive, its key, and then *standard* install:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs)-getdeb apps" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list'
wget -q -O- http://archive.getdeb.net/getdeb-archive.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install rubyripper
```

Tested for **16.04 LTS** (Xenial), **14.04 LTS** (Trusty), and **13.10** (Saucy).

---

Minor issue (11-Aug-2016): *Bug related to non-ASCII characters in track (file)names.* eg. 'é', etc.

Known regression bug (in RubyRipper 0.6.2), see: https://github.com/momodalo/rubyripper/issues/449). Should be address in (upcoming) RubyRipper 0.7.0 .

Comment: Works for me. Note that the double-arrow on the first line should be a single arrow, for explicit overwrite of the target file. Otherwise it grows every time this is repeated.

Comment: Agreed. That was leftover from my other action (back on **13.10**) to add a second line, but with **`saucy-getdeb games`** instead.

Answer (score 3):

Did you ever figure this out? I had similar experience, but eventually found a resolution. First, I tried following the instructions on the community Ubuntu help pages related to CD ripping. Either I couldn't follow the instructions correctly or they were just too outdated and wouldn't work on my box. I'm running 12.04 LTS, btw.

After many hours spent searching and reading, I successfully followed the instructions in post #3 on [here](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+question/145881), summarized below:

1. Install dependencies by typing in the terminal:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install cd-discid cdparanoia flac lame mp3gain normalize-audio ruby-gnome2 ruby vorbisgain
   ```
2. Run each of these commands, one after the other (note, in the fourth one down, replace admin with whatever your username is on your linux box, assuming you have admin privileges):

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install libgettext-ruby1.8 make
   $ cd /usr/local/src
   $ ls -ld .
   $ sudo chgrp admin .
   $ sudo chmod g+w .
   $ wget http://rubyripper.googlecode.com/files/rubyripper-0.6.0.tar.bz2
   $ sha1sum rubyripper-0.6.0.tar.bz2
   $ tar xvjf rubyripper-0.6.0.tar.bz2
   $ cd rubyripper-0.6.0
   $ ./configure --enable-lang-all --enable-gtk2 --enable-cli --prefix=/usr/local
   $ sudo make install
   ```

Note, on my first attempt at following these instructions, I got stuck on the last step (`$ sudo make install`) because the previous step failed to create the make files, which happened because I did not replace "admin" with "scott" in step 4, which meant that my privileges weren't set up properly. To fix that, I had to delete the rubyripper-0.6.0 directory and the tar.bz2 file, redo step 4 with the proper group name of "scott" instead of "admin," and then redo the rest of the steps. When I did step 4 correctly, everything else worked as expected and I was able to finally launch rubyripper (I prefer using the GUI versus the CLI, so I invoke `$ rrip_gui`).

Let me know if you get stuck trying these steps and I will try to help you out.

Comment: These instructions worked flawlessly for LinuxMint 15: olivia as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To install it, follow the below steps:

1.) Download getdeb package, then double-click to install. It adds the getdeb repository to your system.

[Download getdeb package](http://archive.getdeb.net/install_deb/getdeb-repository_0.1-1~getdeb1_all.deb)

2.) Install Synaptic Package Manager from Ubuntu Software Center, then open it. Click on Reload button to update package lists. Finally search for and mark to install rubyripper:

[image]

source: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/07/install-rubyripper-ubuntu-linux-mint/